# Golang, Go : implicitly calling interface function?

Tags: go

http://play.golang.org/p/xjs-jwMsr7

I have this function

```
 func (e *MyError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("AT %v, %s", e.When, e.What)
 }
```

But

as you see below, I never called it but how come it is called in the final output?

```
type MyError struct {
    When time.Time
    What string
}

func (e *MyError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("AT %v, %s", e.When, e.What)
}

func run() error {
    return &MyError{
        time.Now(), "it didn't work",
    }
}

func main() {
    if err := run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fmt.Println` and the other functions in `pkg/fmt` analyze the objects passed to it.
If it is an error, the function calls `.Error()` on the passed object and prints the string
returned by `Error()`.

See [the source](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/fmt/print.go?name=go1.1.2#706) for details. The code says:

```
switch v := p.field.(type) {
case error:
    // ...
    p.printField(v.Error(), verb, plus, false, depth)
    return
// ...
}
```

The type of the passed object is checked in a type switch statement and in case of the object
implementing the [error interface](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Errors), `v.Error()` is used as value.